# add version of app at bottom navigation view is not displayed properly

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

As a lot of people are probably trying to do it, I am trying to add a footer to a navigation view. I did this:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/appVersion"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buildInfoTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

This working fine but not in 2 cases: small screen because the linearlayout overlap the menu and also if the keyboard is popped up, it move the layout.

Any idea how to make sure that the linear layout with the app version stick to the bottom of the navigation or also below the menu item so it's not overlapping on small screen.

Thanks

Comment: Try in your manifest adjust pan size false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once
Note change widget values and parameters as per your requirements.

**OPTION 1-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/content_main"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buildInfoTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

OPTION 2-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/content_main"

            app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buildInfoTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```